# Thumbnail to Full Width Image Header page transition in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, next.js, css-transitions

http://manifesto.clapat.com/

If you click on any project from home page, you get a transition from a thumbnail to a full screen image that becomes the header of that project's page. How are transitions like these created and what is the best way to implement them in preferably NextJs using the internal routing and not React Router, but I can port if someone can get it working with that as well.

There are some tutorials out there, but all of them are loading the data on the same page, sort of a full screen modal component that animates in and not going to another / project page. The main goal is to transition to other page, while keeping the image kind of as a loading state.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need server side rendering for that, since with regular rendering the images start loading once you route to the page. In Next.js all pages that are accessed through Link element are pre-rendered while you are on the page that contains a `<Link>` element that points to it.

For the effect the first thing you have to do is make image `position: fixed` in css, then make a transition that scales image to `width: 100%` and `height: 100%` make it so transition is 500ms, and also make a timeout that routes you to the next page that already has the image as background. I don't know if you have to do this but include somewhere a `<Link href="/next-page" />` so the page is pre-rendered and the image is loaded instantly when routed to it.

first page:

```
const router = useRouter();

const [transitionStarted, setTransitionStarted] = useState<boolean>(false);

function handleClick() {
  setTransitionStarted(true);

  setTimeout(() => {
    router.push("/next-page");
  }, 500)
}

return (
  <div>
    <Link className="hidden" href="/next-page" />
    <Image 
      className={`duration-500 ${transitionStarted ? "fixed w-full h-full top-0 left-0" : "<initial image sizing and styles>"}`} 
      onClick={handleClick}> 
      src="path-to-image" 
      fill 
      alt="image link" />
  </div>
  
)
```

next page:

```
return (
  <div>
    <Image className="fixed w-full h-full top-0 left-0" fill alt="image that is used as background on next page" />
  </div>
)
```

I have written the example in tailwindcss so it's more readable but you can achieve the same thing in any other css library. The only thing you have to do to make the transition smooth is to make the transition-duration and the setTimeout duration the same so the page only redirects once the transition is finished and the two images on both pages are identical.

Hopefully I have gave you the answer you were asking for. Here is the [tailwindcss documentation](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation) if you need to see what the classes are doing in the example.